# Maven-assembly-plugin fails with GC Overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project. One of the modules uses maven-assembly-plugin. When running mvn clean install on the whole project, the build fails with GC Overhead limit exceeded error.

I am using maven 3.3.9 (tried also with 3.2.2). The maven-assembly-plugin is in version 2.5.5 (tried also with 2.6). Here is the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>dist-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>all</classifier>                 
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-all</finalName>
        <attach>false</attach>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>...my main class...</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have even set MAVEN_OPTS to following, but didn't help:

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m"
```

The last message before failing is:

```
Cleaning up unclosed ZipFile for archive .../.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.46/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar
```

Comment: I'm seeing an almost identical problem to this (failing when adding bouncycastle lib)  - but only when the assembly is run as part of a full build. If I run the assembly separately it doesn't fail. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The behavior is exactly as you described. Full build fails, but when I run build on only the one module containing the assemblies it doesn't.

Comment: Thought I had it with the -d64 switch - turns out I had reverted more than I though from GIT :(

Answer (score 4):

Moving to maven-assempbly-plugin version 3.2.0 solved it for me and sped up the build significantly

```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
     .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Suffering with exactly the same problem, I've got it working by simply increasing max heap space to: -Xmx6g